# Laravel 5 Method not found exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 and try to update a form:

```
 {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['edit', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

 {!! Form::label('titel', 'First Name:'!!}
 {!! Form::text('titel', null,) !!}


<button type="submit">Update</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@editUser']);
```

My controller:

```
public function editUser($id){};
```

When click on the update Button I get MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

I checked in the browser source code and saw that Form::model(..) which I use generate the following output:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/myProject/public/edit/1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="4nZlyfzzAZmTcZfThQ8gcR6cgEgYgR0ip0JZTKck">
```

Within the form there is the attribute method="POST" and the hidden input has the attribute value="PUT". This seems not correct for me. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'update' route to actually save the data (validate and persist it to the database). 'edit' route is what you used to generate edit form.

You should use PUT method to run method which saves data.

Also, here is small tip for you. Learn about how RESTful controllers work. They are really easy way to do what you're doing here (defenetly worth to learn them):
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers

Comment: I'm glad I could help. )

Answer (score 2):

Your route is not the same as your form.

Laravel uses the hidden inputs to specify the different http methods, as put.

So in your routes you should use a put method not a post.

```
Route::put();
```